# Prompt options are required for Prompt dialogs (Parameter 'options')

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, botframework, chatbot

I am suing MS Bot Framework and while routing from one waterfall Dialog to another, I am getting this error 'Prompt options are required for Prompt dialogs (Parameter 'options')'. Please help me what could be causing this.
Call from Parent to Child dialog:

```cs
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(DialogType.ChildDialog.ToString(), conversationData, cancellationToken);
```

inside ChildDialog:

```cs
public ChildDialog(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(nameof(ChildDialog))
{
    _
    _conversationDataAccessor = serviceProvider.GetService<UserState>().CreateProperty<ConversationData>(nameof(ConversationData));
    _userState = serviceProvider.GetService<UserState>().CreateProperty<User>(nameof(User));

    var Test = new WaterfallStep[]
    {
        StepOne,
        StepTwo
    };

    _D1 = serviceProvider.GetService<D1>();
    _D2 = serviceProvider.GetService<D2>();

    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(Test), Test));
    AddDialog(new TextPrompt(DialogIds.ChildDialog));
    AddDialog(D1);
    AddDialog(D2);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue and i realized that InitialDialogId property in child dialog was missing.

```
this.InitialDialogId = nameof(Test);
```

It seems you have missing too.

Comment: Thanks @saeed for your response. I will try this and check.

Comment: Same here. ComponentDialog but forgot to set the initial ID to the waterfall dialog.